# What is the best method to store massive amount of strings on c++ allowing fast iteration

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Last year I created a WxWidgets GUI to install ps2 games Into ps2 APA hard drive.

One of the features of this program consists on assigning the original game title to the game while installing the game.

To achieve this, I need both the game title and it's region code (Which follows this naming: `ABCD_123.45`)

The database currently has `15701` entries disposed in a CSV.

The program currently holds this database as a `std::string` array (1 index, 1 line), Which is iterated comparing the obtained ID with the first 11 chars of each line.

I was wondering if there is another method/container that can yield a better performance on the search...

https://github.com/israpps/HDL-Batch-installer/blob/main/Database/gamename.csv

Comment: 15701 strings is not a "massive amount". If locating an ID in that takes a noticeable amount of time, you're doing something strange.

Comment: If The ID is always 11 chars then use a struct ID { char[12]; } and put them in a vector. That will place them in contiguous memory and iteration will be just pointer arithmetic without any indirections. And profile and benchmark your code. Is this really your bottleneck?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow If they were to contain only the id, the `std::string` based strings would in practice also be in contiguous memory due to small string optimisation. Your solution would squeeze the strings a little bit tighter which would save a bit of memory/bandwidth.

Comment: @eerorika Oh right, 12 might still be a small string. See premature optimization comment above. :) I expect the small string would still have some extra overhead because the size would be variable. On the other hand the std::string might be 16 byte and better align to cache lines. A char[16]; might yet be better. MEASURE MEASURE MEASURE.

Comment: A quick experiment iterated over all of those as a `vector<string>´, looking at all initial 11 characters of all the entries, in ~6 milliseconds without any optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering if there is another method/container that can yield a better performance on the search...

Yes. A map would have more asymptotically efficient lookup algorithm compared to the linear search that you currently use.

The standard library has `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` which are easy options, but there are other data structures too such as prefix tries and ordered arrays. `std::unordered_map` is usually a reasonable base choice when you don't need sorted order and when the key has a standard hash function (strings do).

Whether the more asymptotically efficient solution is faster with your problem size in practice, you'll find by measuring.

Comment: If the IDs are all placed in lexicorapical order in a std::vector and distributed fairly uniform then you could do a dictionary lookup costing you O(log log n) iirc. If you are looking for "zoo" in a dictionary you aren't opening at the start or the middle but close to the end. Estimating where the key probably is rather than taking the midpoint improves the lookup over binary search IF the keys are distributed fairly uniform.